# One function call creates double borrow error while other does not

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am a bit confused about what the problem is here, or rather why it happens in one scenario and does not in other.

I am writing a gameboy emulator and implementing a function that increments a register, this is the function, it works fine without any errors:

```rust
    pub fn increment_reg8(
        &mut self,
        register_name: RegisterName,
        register_byte: RegisterByteName,
    ) -> u64 {
        let target_register = &mut self.registers[register_name][register_byte];
        let original_value = *target_register;

        *target_register += 1;
        if *target_register == 0 {
            self.set_flag(Flag::Zero);
        } else {
            self.clear_flag(Flag::Zero);
        }

        4
    }
```

Now I have tried changing the if statement to

```rust
self.set_flag_to(Flag::Zero, *target_register == 0);
```

Which pretty much equals the same if statement from before

```rust
    fn set_flag_to(&mut self, flag: Flag, value: bool) {
        if value {
            self.set_flag(flag);
        } else {
            self.clear_flag(flag);
        }
    }
```

Why does this change create double borrow error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting corner case of the borrow checker. `self` is being used by two things: `set_flag` (equivalently, `clear_flag`) and `target_register`, which is a mutable reference to data inside of `self`. Let's look at your first example.

```
*target_register += 1;
if *target_register == 0 {
    self.set_flag(Flag::Zero);
} else {
    self.clear_flag(Flag::Zero);
}
```

A naive borrow checker would reject this. `target_register` has a mutable reference to part of `self`, and `set_flag` / `clear_flag` need mutable access to all of `self`, so that's a double borrow.

But Rust's borrow checker isn't naive. It's quite clever. It sees that `target_register` is never used again, so it automatically drops the value in order to get the lease on `self` back. Rust just silently converted your code to this.

```
*target_register += 1;
if *target_register == 0 {
    drop(target_register);
    self.set_flag(Flag::Zero);
} else {
    drop(target_register);
    self.clear_flag(Flag::Zero);
}
```

Where `drop` is [`std::mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html).

Now your second example.

```
self.set_flag_to(Flag::Zero, *target_register == 0);
```

Again, `set_flag_to` wants a mutable reference to `self`, and `target_register` is already a mutable reference to `self`. [Argument evaluation order](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order-of-operands) in Rust happens left to right, and the `self.method()` syntax is syntax sugar for this.

```
YourType::set_flag_to(self, Flag::Zero, *target_register == 0);
```

So the `self` argument gets evaluated. This borrows all of `self` mutably. `Flag::Zero` isn't complicated, so it passes the borrow checker. But *now* we need to access `target_register` again. But we already borrowed `self` mutably, so we can't do that. And since we need `target_register` *after* the `self` borrow, we can't auto drop anything like we did before.

If you change the evaluation order so that `target_register` is evaluated before `self`, it'll pass again.

```
let is_zero = *target_register == 0;
self.set_flag_to(Flag::Zero, is_zero);
```

This will pass the borrow checker, since Rust silently converts it into

```
let is_zero = *target_register == 0;
drop(target_register);
self.set_flag_to(Flag::Zero, is_zero);
```

and we can borrow `&mut self` when we need to for that last line.